# Iterating through array of string in react getinitialProps and passing it to an await function in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ethereum

```js
static async getInitialProps() {
        
        const campaigns = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call();
        const campaign = Campaign(campaigns[0]);//call the contract to be able to use the methods inside the campaign
        const summary = await campaign.methods.getSummary().call();
        return { campaigns,summary };//campaigns is given to campaignIndex as an object
    }
    
    


     renderCampaigns()  {
       
          const  items =  this.props.campaigns.map(address => {
            
             return {
                header: this.props.summary[7] ,
                description:(
                <Segment >
                    <Progress percent={this.props.summary[1]/this.props.summary[6]} attached='bottom' success/>
                    <Card.Content description = {'balance: '+ web3.utils.fromWei(this.props.summary[1], 'ether') + ' ' + 'ether'}   textAlign='right'/>
                    
                </Segment>
                
                ),
                extra:(  
                <Link route={`/campaigns/${address}`}>
                <a>View Campaign</a>
                </Link>
                
                ),
                fluid: true,//card takes width of the container
                //percentage goal of the event),
                link: true,
                meta:(
                    <Segment>
                        <Card.Content header ={'Description: '+ this.props.summary[5]} textAlign='left'/>
                        <Card.Content description = {'Goal: '+ this.props.summary[6] +' wei'} textAlign='left'/>
                    </Segment>
                )
                 
                
               
                
            };
        
             
        });
```

So my problem is that I want to go through an array of string provided by campaigns and pass each string to my function campaign and just after that be able to call the methods found in the class campaign through summary. Since summary is an await function my loop needs to be an async loop.I have tried to 
 create an array of objects in which in the mapping of the string I push all the data from my summary array in it but I get an out of scope error from which it says that my mapping is not async.[Snippet of my actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ7gn.png) I just want to get an idea how to create an async function in which I can map all the strings from campaigns in it get my data from summary and return an array of data to render below

Comment: It would help to put the code snippet in your post and not a link to a screenshot.

Comment: I'm sorry.I've just updated it if you want to take a look